# service/provider error handling best practice

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

to get data from firestore I implemented a service and a provider. for error handling I just used a bool, but this seems like not best practice. How can I write that in a better way?

Provider:

```
Future createNewUser(String userName) async {
    var fbAuth = await auth.currentUser;
    if(fbAuth != null) {
      return await AppUserService.createNewUser(fbAuth.uid);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

AppUserService:

```
static Future<bool> createNewUser(String uId) async {
    try {
      await firestoreUsers.doc(uId).set({
        ...
      });
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      logger.e('error creating user: $e');
      return false;
    }
  }
```

calling the function:

```
var creationSuccess =
        await Provider.of<AppUserProvider>(context, listen: false).createNewUser();
```

Comment: Consider using exceptions instead of boolean values for error handling. Throw exceptions in your service methods and catch them when calling those methods to provide more context and improve error handling. Alternatively, you can return failure or success objects from your service methods, which gives you more control over handling errors. This approach allows you to avoid exceptions altogether and provides a clear way to communicate success or failure.
want to know more about either type? => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69219085/what-is-left-and-right-in-the-either-module-in-flutter